# NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have a production enviroment where we use honeybadger.
We frequently get 'NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass' but without a stack. How can that be logged inside our rails app separately so we can maybe catch the stack and to find out what is causing that?

Thanks

Comment: Does this occure **only** in production environment and not in dev/test?

Comment: Not that we are aware of

Comment: As I said, we are using HoneyBadger but the trace is empty

Comment: Ah, indeed. That's weird.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using them already then there are some tools which you could add to your application for monitoring your app for errors in a better way:

1. [Errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) which is
2. [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/languages/rails_exception_handling) API compliant and even
3. [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/ruby?utm_campaign=Search%20-%20APM%20-%20Rails%20Troubleshooting%20&%20Errors%20-%20EMEA%20-%20BMM&utm_medium=PS&utm_source=GEMEA&utm_content=%20%20rails%20%20error%20%20handling&kclickid=622d065e-506b-49fc-bb9f-732650763679&gclid=CIzVgJbEmNUCFRxJGQod7wICkA) which is maybe rather big piece of tool for only error-monitoring

These might give you better clearer understanding of what you are facing with.

Comment: our app has the same issue, but don't bother to use airbrake since it reports no trace either as our app is currently on it. All it throws is the exception not even with which file it happens